# Welcher Satz ist richtig und Warum?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, grammaticality, relative-clause

Welcher Satz ist richtig und Warum?

1. > Sie hat Magengeschwür, wodurch Blutdruckanstieg und Störungen im Urogenitalsystem verursacht wird.
2. > Sie hat Magengeschwür, was ihr Blutdruckanstieg und Störungen im Urogenitalsystem verursacht.
3. > Sie hat Magengeschwür, das ihr Blutdruckanstieg und Störungen im Urogenitalsystem verursacht.

Comment: Keiner der drei Sätze ist richtig, weil das Nomen *Magengeschwür* hier nicht ohne ein [Determinativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)) (z.B. einen Artikel) stehen kann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None is completely correct.

> 1. Sie hat ein Magengeschwür, wodurch Blutdruckanstieg und Störungen im Urogenitalsystem verursacht werden.
> 2. Sie hat ein Magengeschwür, was bei ihr Blutdruckanstieg und Störungen im Urogenitalsystem verursacht.
> 3. Sie hat ein Magengeschwür, das bei ihr Blutdruckanstieg und Störungen im Urogenitalsystem verursacht.
> 4. Sie hat ein Magengeschwür, welches bei ihr Blutdruckanstieg und Störungen im Urogenitalsystem verursacht.

To explain: All sentences need an *ein*. *Magengeschwür* doesn't work without an article.

For the first *Sie hat ein Magengeschwür* as a whole is a fact. *Wodurch* explains what happens because of the fact. Since several things happen it has to be plural.

Using *was* is colloquial, *welches* would be more correct. *Das* and *welches* are interchangable in this case. In example 2 and 3 you are describing what happens to her, so it needs to say *bei ihr*. The verb in these cases is singular because so is *ein Magengeschwür*.